# How to use sql table row items (or other alternatives) as a queue for multiple servers

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, queue, message-queue

I have 10 ubuntu servers running on aws as ec2 instance and a list of arguments which I need to run in each server. Outputs are saved to a PSQL database.

The arguments is a list of 1000 items which looks like this.

```
args 

arg1
arg2
arg3
..
..
arg1000
```

I split up the list into 10 parts evenly, so each server runs 100 arguments to cut down time.

So `server1` opens up a file that has the following list, `server2` would have args 101-200, etc.

```
args 

arg1
arg2
arg3
..
..
arg100
```

`server1` opens up a function like this,

```
import pandas as pd
from my_functions import my_function, save_return_value_sql_db

df = pd.read_csv(arguments_file.csv)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    return_value = my_function(row[0])
    save_return_value_sql_db(return_value)
```

It saves the output value in a PSQL table called `return_values`.

The arguments take a different amount of time. Sometimes 3 of the servers take an hour longer than the other 7. So there is an imbalance among the arguments even though each server takes 100 arguments.

So I want to make a change to this.

I want to create a central argument_list in separate PSQL table called `states` and as the ubuntu servers go though the list (sharing the same list), they will change a flag in another column and move on to the next row or argument.

I am worried that multiple servers hit up the same row or argument and run the argument command at the same time on multiple servers. Is there a way around this so that no argument is run more than once by any of the 10 servers.

What I have so far is this, I created an sql table with 2 columns that looks like this,

```
args     state

arg1     0
arg2     0
arg3     0
..
..
arg1000  0
```

The servers run this python script,

```
import sqlalchemy
from my_engines import STATE_ENGINE
from my_functions import my_function, save_return_value_sql_db

arg_list = STATE_ENGINE.execute(f"SELECT * FROM states WHERE state = 0 order by args asc").fetchall()

current_arg = arg_list[0][0]

STATE_ENGINE.execute(f"UPDATE states SET state = 1 WHERE args = '{current_arg}'")

return_value = my_function(current_arg)
save_return_value_sql_db(return_value)
```

How do I modify this code so that the 10 servers don't run any of the args more than once or crash because the state has been set to 1 and is unable to set it to 1 because another server is trying to do the same thing?

Is there another data structure or library I can use to achieve what I am trying to do that would make things easier? I have no idea where to start. I googled a little and I saw something called rabbitmq and zeromq but I have no idea how they work or if they’re right for this.

Comment: Have you read [this article](https://shekhargulati.com/2022/01/27/correctly-using-postgres-as-queue/)? Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: @markalex it's similar to one of the answers, but I am looking for something in python or sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start a transaction and use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM states WHERE state = 0
order by args asc
LIMIT 100 -- otherwise the first worker would consume the whole list
FOR NO KEY UPDATE SKIP LOCKED -- if other workers already holds 100 rows, take next 100
```

for a cheap concurrency mechanism.

Comment: how would the for loop be done within each server?